# Is there an easier (more efficient) way to iterate through table values first, then indexes in Lua?

Tags: lua, iteration, lua-table

Currently, I have the following code:

```
runtable={}
for _,v in pairs(akeys) do
  if string.match(string.upper(v),string.upper(area)) then
    table.insert(runtable,area)
    break
  end
end

if #runtable = 0 then
  for i,_ in pairs(akeys) do
    if string.match(string.upper(i),string.upper(area)) then
    table.insert(runttable,area)
    end
  end
end
```

The purpose of this script is to go through all the values first and see if the area variable matches the value. If it does, it's going to be a one-time thing, so it'll stop the loop and continue on with the rest of the script (beyond the `if #runtable = 0`). If it fails to find anything in the values, then it goes through the list again, but this time comparing indices to the area, and each time it finds a match (partial or full), it'll add it to the runtable.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or is this the best possible way to run this, regardless of how cluttered it may look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local rt1, rt2 = {}, {}
for i,v in pairs(akeys) do
  if string.match(string.upper(v),string.upper(area)) then
    table.insert(rt1,area)
    break
  end
  if string.match(string.upper(i),string.upper(area)) then
    table.insert(rt2,area)
  end
end

local runtable = #rt1 > 0 and rt1 or rt2
```

Not a huge saving in terms of ugliness, but it saves a second loop.  Sadly there's no kind of magic I'm aware of that'll make this much prettier, but that's one of the tradeoffs of having a language as compact as Lua.

Comment: Thanks! I really just wanted to avoid the whole two loops thing. I'll use this in place of the code I had before.